# Make on-prem Public Folders visible to 365 users: EXO can't see PFMailbox1

Tags: office365, exchange-server, hybrid, public-folders

I am trying to make our On-Prem Public folders visible to our 365 users within our hybrid environment.

**I have been using this Guide:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/exchange/hybrid-deployment/set-up-modern-hybrid-public-folders?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The problem however is found in the first step. I can find PFMAILBOX1 in the on-prem Exchange Management Shell using *Get-mailbox -publicfolder*. However, I cannot see the same box in the Exchange Online powershell (opened powershell and used command *connect-exchangeonline*. That should be correct right?). When using the command *get-mailuser PF** nothing is found.

Azure AD Connect's Exchange Mail Public Folders is enabled.

While PFMAILBOX1 cannot be seen with the get-mailuser command in EXO, other on-prem mailboxes are listed. So it is just the PFMailbox1 that isn't being synced.

**I would like to add:** I am aware that Public folders are outdated in the first place. However, We are now migrating the user mailboxes to the cloud first, and we want them to be able to read the on-prem PF's for the time being. After that is done, we are going to see if we can migrate the folders altogether.

## pushing through anyway

I have tried carrying on the procedure anyways. The first comment on prem works correctly:

> .\Sync-ModernMailPublicFolders.ps1 -CsvSummaryFile:sync_summary.csv

The second command done on Exchange Online gets the following error:

> C:\Users\admin> Set-OrganizationConfig -PublicFoldersEnabled Remote -RemotePublicFolderMailboxes PFMailbox1
> Write-ErrorMessage : Ex94914C|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundException|Couldn't find object "PFMailbox1". Please make sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different object.

Again: in On-Prem Exchange Shell, I can see PFMAILBOX1 with the following commando:

> Get-mailbox -publicfolder

## AD object

PFMAILBOX1 also has an AD object. I saw that the user logon names where a little peculiar:

Gb43e01734903491ea07486cd2556fadf@contoso.nl

Contoso\PF44d9f59c32174b1486

## ADSI

I did see a weird error message in eventvwr:

> Process w3wp.exe (AutoDisc) (PID=14976). Object [CN=Contoso,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=Contoso,DC=local]. Property [RemotePublicFolderMailboxes] is set to value [Contoso.local/Deleted Objects/PFMailbox1
> DEL:3395c8f8-974a-4b9e-81d6-acefc58628c6], it is pointing to the Deleted Objects container in Active Directory. This property should be fixed as soon as possible.

Now this is weird. I have checked, but this account was not listed when searching through the deleted accounts. PFMAILBOX1 is a AD object that exists as a non-deleted user. I suspect that maybe a previous admin has accidentally deleted, and then restored or remade PFMailbox1, though I am not too sure.

I navigated to CN=Contoso,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=Contoso,DC=local, and here, the attribute **pFContacts** has a value that points to the deleted PFMailbox1 user.
I am tempted to just change this value to the CN of the actual PFMAILbox1 user (*CN=PFMailbox1,CN=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=local*), but I am not if that is what this value is supposed to point to. If so, please confirm. if not, please tell me what it is supposed to reference to instead.

The public folder mailboxes do seem to point to the existing PFMailbox1 user in the attribute **msExchPublicFolderMailbox** (This would be: *CN=PFMailbox1,CN=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=local*)